# Rav Moshe and Giving Your Time for Charity

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, time, maaser-tithes, moshe-feinstein

I recall hearing that Rav Moshe Feinstein rules that one should donate a tenth of his time to learn with other Jews, in addition to the more commonly accepted 'tithe' of money. The only source I was able to find this referenced in was an [Aish article](http://www.aish.com/atr/130196983.html) that quotes an interview of Rav Moshe in the Jewish Observer where he made that claim.

Does anyone know if this is brought down anywhere else, specifically in Igros Moshe? Or alternatively, what it would be filed under in the Yad Moshe, as I couldn't find it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118823/759

Answer (score 8):

Following @Yirmeyahu's lead I found my copy of the Eye of the Needle with the full copy of the article you are looking for. I scanned it below. See end of page 3 and page 4. It is not a straight interview of R Moshe Feinstein but an essay based on his call for action to yeshiva students.

[image: RMF interview J Observer 1973_Page_1]
[image: RMF interview J Observer 1973_Page_2]
[image: RMF interview J Observer 1973_Page_3]
[image: RMF interview J Observer 1973_Page_4]

Answer (score 5):

I have spent time over several days unsuccessfully trying to locate my copy of "Eye of the Needle" (which incidentally I see is recommended in the link you provided) but in the index there is a copy of the Jewish Observer article which you and your source have mentioned. My recollection of the article is that it didn't merely mention this idea in his name but rather the whole article originated with him. The origin of the article is explained [here](http://klalperspectives.org/rabbi-asher-resnick/) "Rav Moshe Feinstein zt”l, in a call to action that was directed to yeshiva students and published in the Jewish Observer in June, 1973". Using one's time to *lehrn* Torah with the less capable [is also](http://klalperspectives.org/rabbi-moshe-hauer-2/) also mentioned in the Igros Moshe:

> אך הוריתי שכל ת"ח אף שצריך לעצמו והוא גדול מאד מחוייב ללמד מקצת זמן גם עם אחרים אף שמתבטל מתורת עצמו...ומסתבר לי שהוא ג"כ שיעור מעשר עשירית הזמן (אגרות משה אה"ע ד:כו(ד))  ץ

On Shabbos I noticed that this idea is mentioned in the Stone Chumash:

> *R' Moshe Feinstein* stated that a Jew should tithe not only his possessions, but also his time, by contributing time to the service of worthy causes. (comment on Genesis 28:22)

It is not clear that their source is independent of those mentioned above.

Comment: I found the essay you were looking for and scanned it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m85r00vd5hxuuom/RMF%20interview%20J%20Observer%201973.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

The Teshuvah is in Igros Moshe, Even Hoezer, Chelek 7 See http://www.hebrewbooks.org/921, Siman 26 on page 55.