# Earliest Sources for Giving Maaser of Time

Tags: time, maaser-tithes

Rav Moshe Feinstein writes in a teshuva [(EH 4:26:4)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=52) that one must give a tenth of his time for others the same way one should give a tenth of his money. What are the earlier sources for such a concept?

Comment: Rav Moshe [in Vol. 9 pg. 368] suggests it as a possibility "אפשר לומר", not as a "must", so there most likely is no source that he knew of.

Comment: וְכֹל אֲשֶׁר תִּתֶּן לִי עַשֵּׂר אֲעַשְּׂרֶנּוּ לָךְ

Comment: very similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48828/759

Comment: I recall a similar concept from Chasam Sofer, who is minutely earlier than R Chaim Palagi quoted in the answer

Comment: I know of a pshat from the Chida on a gemara in Kesubos. Would that be considered a source from the Chida or from Talmud Bavli?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi [Haim Palachi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim_Palachi) ([Nefesh Haim, *ma’arechet* Hei n. 7; s.v. ונלע״ד](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8954&st=&pgnum=131)) articulated the idea of “tithing” one’s time by spreading or teaching Torah.

Similarly, Rabbi [Shimon Shkop](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimon_Shkop) ([Share Yosher, intro., s.v. וכן](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53151&st=&pgnum=18)) expressed the importance of “spiritual tithes” whereby one enables another to grow in Torah.